# Submitting a form to a Rails server from jQuery using AJAX isn't working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip

I'm trying to upload some data from a from to a Rails server using AJAX. The form contains two text inputs and one file input. Here's what my `submit` event handler looks like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    type: $(this).attr("method"),
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

This works fine in every browser except IE. When I try to submit the form in IE, my Rails server spits out the following error:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: bad content body
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:117:in `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:19:in `block in parse'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:17:in `loop'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:17:in `parse'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `parse_multipart'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:377:in `parse_multipart'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:203:in `POST'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:26:in `method_override'
        /Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:14:in `call'
        ...
```

I'd appreciate any insights into why this might not be working.

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentType?

Comment: I've tried removing `contentType: false` and I've tried explicitly setting it to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Neither worked.

Comment: did you use enctype='multipart/form-data' in your form? If you are uploading any file, how contentType can be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. It should be `'multipart/form-data'`, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: What data does `new FormData(@_element.find("form").get(0))` provide?

Comment: Oops. I pulled this code from my application's CoffeeScript, and I converted it to JavaScript to make it more accessible. I missed the `@`'s. This should read `new FormData(this._element.find("form").get(0))`

Comment: I've edited the question to make it simpler.

Comment: Can you just add a csrf token before making the ajax call

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't mention that the CSRF token is present in the form as a hidden input. The submit handler is working in all other browsers *except* IE.

Comment: Yep Please try to add a csrf token before making the ajax call and let us know.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. The CSRF token is already there. If it weren't, the request would fail in all browsers, not just IE.

Comment: Nope using javascript add a csrf token .. Let me add it in my answer though i am not sure about the exact issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a `<script>` tag in the new content? If so, try it without that bit. I've seen some versions of ie have troube with js updates containing that tag...

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by the new content? Are you talking about the return value of the Ajax call?

Comment: I am, assuming said content is being inserted into the page.

Comment: Wow, that was a great insight. Yep, that was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The worst part about it was I was using `<script type="text/template">`, so the browser should have never tried to run it in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bug with IE10/11's serializing of form data. According to a blog post, those versions of IE corrupt the request when the last checkable input is not checked.

[1] http://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's *really* interesting. I assumed my problem had something to do with my file input, but after reading that post I tried removing it and I'm still experiencing the same issue. I tried implementing the suggested workaround; I added a `<input type="hidden" name="ie_workaround">` element as the last element in the form before the submit input, and it didn't fix the problem. Can you think of any other fixes that might work? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `csrf token` before making a AJAX call. something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    set_csrf_token();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      type: $(this).attr("method"),
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });

  function set_csrf_token() {
    // for  protectting from forgery and sending the x-csrf token
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      }
    });  
  }
});
```

I assume you are uploading a file using the form . Using jQuery file upload it submit the form using a hidden iframe. some time IE change the file content type like .jpeg will be .pjpeg that also may can the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're insisting the problem is the CSRF token. I double checked the body of the request in Chrome and it's being passed along with the rest of the form's data. In Rails, the authenticity token is stored in a hidden input inside the form. To be sure, I tried setting the token as a header as you suggested in your answer, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Paperclip.

Comment: please check the content .. IE changes the content type some type like i have mentioned . jpeg will be pjpeg ..

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `FormData`, I used the [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/), which fixed the problem.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ajaxSubmit();
});
```

Comment: While this solves my problem, it doesn't answer my question. I'd also prefer a solution without an extra dependency, so I won't accept this answer.